# How to change the url of my webapp in tomcat server?

Tags: eclipse, spring, url, tomcat, url-rewriting

The directory structure in eclipse is - 

`MyProjectName(
 WebContent(
  META-INF(
   MANIFEST.MF
  ), 
  app(
   appname(
    index.html
   )
  ), 
  WEB-INF(web.xml)
 )
)`

I can access my project on tomcat7 using
 `http://localhost:8080/MyProjectName/app/appname/index.html`
I want to access it using 
 `http://localhost:8080/MyProjectName/`

I am not using any other code than html/js/css and all the code is in Webapps directory only.

Spring, Tomcat7, windows7 is platform.

Comment: anybody got a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

### if its a welcome file use like this below in web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>/app/appname/index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: no, with the above solution the url still remains localhost:8080/MyProjectName/app/appname/  but I want the url to be just localhost:8080/MyprojectName/